error while installing docker apps in OpenMediaVault
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I can install the portainer without any problem, but I can't install other applications like CUPS and others.
The error I get is like this
docker: failed to register layer: archive/tar: invalid tar header.
root@openmediavault:~# docker run -d -p 631:631 -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus --name cupsd olbat/cupsd

Unable to find image 'olbat/cupsd:latest' locally

latest: Pulling from olbat/cupsd

8549aebbcea8: Pull complete

f6cbb29703a3: Extracting 237MB/237MB

dabb3653c1d2: Download complete

0e63aa34ec5e: Download complete

docker: failed to register layer: archive/tar: invalid tar header.

See 'docker run --help'.

I have tried reinstalling docker on OpenMediaVault on the homer server and still error, I tried installing OpenMediaVault in a virtual machine then installing the application and it worked. I don't know where I went wrong
